# test for Android Fragment only passes when executed first

Tags: java, unit-testing, android-fragments

I'm writing unit tests for an `Activity` that calls a `Fragment`, specifically [this class](https://github.com/amzn/fire-app-builder/blob/master/TVUIComponent/lib/src/main/java/com/amazon/android/tv/tenfoot/ui/activities/ContentDetailsActivity.java). Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ContentDetailsActivityTest {

    private ContentDetailsActivity mContentDetailsActivity;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ContentDetailsActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>
            (ContentDetailsActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mContentDetailsActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mContentDetailsActivity = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void onCreate() throws Exception {
        ContentDetailsFragment mFragment = (ContentDetailsFragment) mContentDetailsActivity
                .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_details_fragment);

        assertTrue(mFragment.isVisible());
    }

    @Test
    public void onActionListUpdateRequired() throws Exception {
        // [irrelevant]
    }

    @Test
    public void onStart() throws Exception {
        // [irrelevant]
    }

    @Test
    public void onStop() throws Exception {
        // [irrelevant]
    }
}
```

Here is the XML layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name="com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.fragments.ContentDetailsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/content_details_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Each test passes when run individually. However, when the tests are run together, `onCreate()` fails due to the `Fragment` being null. I can fix this by naming the tests so that `onCreate()` is called first, but I believe that's a bad practice because unit tests are supposed to be independent of each other.

From my research, this is due to the `Activity` not being recreated properly at the start of each test. I added an `mContentDetailsActivity.recreate()` to my `setUp()` method and an `@UiThreadTest` annotation to each method; while this fixes the `onCreate()` issue, half of the other tests fail, alternating between successes and failures.

Anyone know of a solution?

Edit: added the XML layout.

Comment: Can you post the XML layout for the activity?

Comment: Sure, I just added it.

Comment: In what order are the tests typically run? Can you show the other tests? (I understand why you did not include them in your original question, but since the order of the tests seems to cause issues, I am interested in seeing what the other tests do in order to get some clues as to the cause of the problem and hopefully a fix.) Perhaps just one other test will be sufficient.

Comment: They're run in the order of `onActionListUpdateRequired()`, `onStart()`, `onStop()` and `onCreate()`. The other three tests are actually blank and don't do anything yet.

Comment: What happens if you only add `@UiThreadTest` to each test method, but not `mContentDetailsActivity.recreate()`? (Sorry for all the back and forth with questions. I am just trying to help you diagnose what is going on.)

Comment: `onCreate()` still fails while others pass. However, the error is now a `RuntimeException` with the message `Could not launch intent Intent` instead of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: you should post a new question. More than one, even. Be sure to include details about the errors.